# What is the best way to avoid the Container Inject in services in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony5

Usually to access the file related things or some container features. What is best way to avoid this heavy operation. Ex.To upload the file usually we use like the this.

```
$path = $this->container->getParameter('app.media_documents_path');
$uniqueName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();
$file->move($this->container->getParameter('app.media_documents_directory'), $uniqueName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative way. We can use service to handle this like,

```
bind:
     $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

`$projectDir` can be directly accessed in services. But I want more simpler way here, because both solution are very heavy in real application.

Comment: Even though you asked the question, you should answer it like if you were answering to a different person. Try making the answer objective and clear adding also supporting information.